# Is it possible to know the request amount average in a S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, monitoring, rate-limiting

We are eventually receiving an Rate Limit error from S3 bucket when users try to access the static content. After some research we discovered that S3 buckets have a default rate limit of 5.5k requests per second, which is far more than we need and use, and here is the problem.

We do know by monitoring tools that our app is not receiving that amount of requests, but, can we check directly from the S3 bucket? Maybe we are been flooded somehow and we just want to make sure.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edited:**

The Istvan's answer helped me in discovering S3 Requests Metric, which does exactly what I was searching for. In addition, for those who need to dive into more informations about S3 requests, there's another approach which is:

- enable server access logs in the S3 bucket configs, pointing them to another (new) bucket;
- create a new database and table on Amazon Athena, for querying S3 logs in a SQL-like approach.

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is advanced monitoring for S3 buckets. It is highly recommended to front your S3 bucket with CloudFront in case users accessing it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-monitoring.html

> Request metrics ‐ Monitor Amazon S3 requests to quickly identify and
> act on operational issues. The metrics are available at 1-minute
> intervals after some latency to process. These CloudWatch metrics are
> billed at the same rate as the Amazon CloudWatch custom metrics. For
> information about CloudWatch pricing, see Amazon CloudWatch pricing.
> To learn how to opt in to getting these metrics, see CloudWatch
> metrics configurations.
>
> When enabled, request metrics are reported for all object operations.
> By default, these 1-minute metrics are available at the Amazon S3
> bucket level. You can also define a filter for the metrics collected
> using a shared prefix or object tag. This allows you to align metrics
> filters to specific business applications, workflows, or internal
> organizations.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/

Comment: Request metrics from S3 was the answer I was looking for. Thanks Istvan.